# How to populate a dropdown box using mysqli prepared statements (PHP)

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I am trying to figure out how to populate a dropdown menu in a form with data from a MySQL table. I have found the PHP manual online to be a little helpful (http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php), but I am still not fully understanding it.

Here is what I have so far...

```
function fillBuildings() {

    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM buildings");
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();

    while ($stmt 

 }
```

I know how to build the form and such one I get the data, I just don't know what I should be looping through to get the data.

Comment: `while ($stmt`? And that's all?

Comment: you seem to have given up with out actully trying anything

Comment: If you close the statement before iterating through the results you might indeed have issues.

Comment: I wasn't sure what to put after $stmt... I am very new to using prepared statements

Comment: multiple examples on the manual page you linked to, i'm confused

Comment: There is no reason to use prepared statements for queries without variable values.

Comment: So prepared statements are more for insert queries?

Comment: @user2363217 Or select/update/alter/delete queries where you use a POSTed value.

Comment: So what would be the correct query type to fill a dropbox?

Comment: @user2363217 Don't get me wrong, there is nothing inherently wrong with using a prepared statement here. It is just *more secure* than it needs to be. Like putting a padlock on a jail cell. It doesn't improve the security, but it doesn't hurt.

Comment: So if I did want to use prepared statements, what would the proper code look like? Even linking to an example that loops through the data would help.

Comment: Unfortunately, SO is giving me a timeout error trying to post my answer.  LOL

Comment: Could you put it in the answers section?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could be selecting specific columns and binding the results.

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT `id`, `name` FROM `buildings`");
$stmt->bind_result($id, $name);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();

$blds = array();
while($stmt->fetch()){
    $blds[] = array(
        "id"  => $id,
        "name"=> $name
    );
}

?>

<select>
    <?php for($i = 0; $i < count($blds); $i++):?>
    <option value="<?=$blds[$i]["id"]?>"><?=$blds[$i]["name"]?></option>
    <?php endfor;?>
</select>
```

Comment: So I can't remove that first line hahaha

Comment: Oops. Extra comma in the query